# Deleting Files Older than 30 Days with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete all files in a directory and all files in its sub-directories older than 30 days, leaving all folders intact. This question seems to have been asked to death online and I have this solution which i got from Stackoverflow:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$path = "path-to"

# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
```

Now this works and it doesn't.
When I try this on certain directories it works fine and exits normally. But when I try it on others I get this error:

```
Get-ChildItem : The given path's format is not supported.
At C:path-to-whatever\ClearFiles.ps1:5 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsCo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I assume this is because of the time format in `$._CreationTime`, I have tried to remove this but when I do it continually asks me if i really want to delete the following files because I have not specified the recursive parameter, which I have at the beginning.

Could anyone clear this up? And perhaps explain why it works on some directories and not others.

Cheers

Comment: Do any of your paths contain special characters? Perhaps -LiteralPath would be better. Either way something is wrong with `$path` which we cannot see in your code.

Comment: I will give literpath a try

Comment: It would be better if you show an example of a path that generates this error.

Comment: The path: $path = "\\s44b1808\jsm\instance\File-Dev"

I thought it might have been the '\\' but like I was saying it works on some some directories that have this at the beginning

Comment: How long are your paths including the filename?

Comment: An example would be:
\\s44b1808\jsm\instance\File-Liv\BRMW00024042.xml

This may work it may not. Like I was saying it works with some and not others.

The failure I have shown above is when all the sub directories are empty. So technically it should just run and then stop. But it fails.

Comment: That example is when a directory has files and this might run fine.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce your issue with the following code, but I will explain how I did it with some error handling ideas.

Lets first compare the two variables.

`$_.LastWriteTime` = Last time the file was written to.
`$_.CreationTime` = Time the file was created or Copy and pasted.

Adding the `Out-GridView` with the `Select` statement will provide us with a list of files on that path. I have added the Name, Attributes, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, and Fullname.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $Date } | Select Name, Attributes, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, Fullname | Out-GridView
```

If you Run As Administrator you could see more files. Certain hidden directories requires Run As Administrator.

Remove-Item has a really nice option of -WhatIf. What if we decide to delete the folders and files. WhatIf option doesn't delete, but it will show you what would have been deleted. Great for testing.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse  | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $Date } | Remove-Item -Recurse -whatif
```

Lets put this into a working Function with some error handling:

```
Function Remove_FilesCreatedBeforeDate{
$Path="F:\ISO\"
$Date=(Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$ValidPath = Test-Path $Path -IsValid
If ($ValidPath -eq $True) {
Write-Host "Path is OK and Cleanup is now running"
#Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $Date } | Select Name, Attributes, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, Fullname | Out-GridView
#Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $Date } | Remove-Item -Recurse -whatif
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse  | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $Date } #| Remove-Item -Recurse -Verbose
}
Else {Write-Host "Path is not a ValidPath"}
}
    Remove_FilesCreatedBeforeDate
```

You only see the Warning\Confirm menu when you are about to delete a folder structure. What a lot of people fail to understand is the -Force option only removes hidden files and read-only files. We will want to use the -Recurse option to avoid this prompt, but note that it will delete everything.

I have commented out the Remove-Item for safety reasons.
`#| Remove-Item -Recurse -Verbose`

This works with `$Path` options like `\\SERVER\$C\Directory\` or `C:\Directory\`. Let me know if you have any issues with this function.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have abandoned PowerShell and re-done it in c# with no problems at all.

Comment: Also I found out that there were 3 files in a huge stack of them that had a ':' in them that was causing the powershell to fall over. I couldnt use batch as it does not support UNC paths. Hence it being much easier to write this in c#.

Comment: C# is a powerful as well. Glad it helped, maybe it helps somone in the future. The Colon issue inside the file or folder name is not allowed in Windows, but it is allowed in Unix/Linux maybe even Apple device. This could be fixed in the Unix/Linux system or on the windows side.